# Perfect matching proof for a bipartite graph with specific properties

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Consider a bipartite graph $G=(L\cup R,E)$ where $|L|=|R|=k$. The set of neighbors of a vertex $v\in V$ is defined as $N(v)$. The bipartite graph has the following properties:

1) $|N(v)|\geq 1$

2) $|\bigcup_{\forall l \in L}N(l)|=k$

Prove that a perfect matching exists for the bipartite graph $G$.

I know that I have to use Hall's marriage theorem here but I don't know how to prove that for all subsets of $L$, the number of neighbors is as big as the subsets for $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false for all $k\geq 3$. Consider the bipartite graph which has a special vertex $r\in R$ and $l\in L$ such that an edge is part of the graph if and only if $r$ or $l$ is one of the endpoints.

A counterexample for $k=3$:

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer with an example.